# Store function mappings and arguments in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, python-curses

I try to write a method that handles keyboard input and executes a proper function (optionally with some arguments). Therefore I'm using a dict with some keyboard mappings like

```
mappings = {
    'q'      : (quit         , None),
    KEY_HOME : (move_to_line , 1),
    KEY_END  : (move_to_line , widget.last_line)
}
```

The handler function itself looks like:

```
def handle_input(user_input):

    if user_input in mappings.keys():
        func = mappings[user_input][0]
        args = mappings[user_input][1]
        if args == None:
            func()
        elif type(args) == list:
            func(*args)
        elif type(args) == dict:
            func(**args)
        else:
            func(args)
```

Now, the function works well for the first two dict entries. In case of the third entry, it does not work if `widget.last_line` changes. The python compiler seems to handle this entry as a constant value, even though it is a property of the widget. Is there a way to keep such an entry "volatile", or is there a better way to perform such an operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to store a reference to an attribute in the way you want. What you can do instead though is write a new function that fetches the attribute when it is called, then passes the value at that time to `move_to_line`:

```
KEY_END  : (lambda: move_to_line(widget.last_line), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change last entry on this: `KEY_END  : (move_to_last_line , widget)`

Where `move_to_last_line` is:

```
def move_to_last_line(widget):
  move_to_line(widget.last_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think even if it's a property, the *value* of the property is changed. Consider this: class Person: name
p = Person('Mike')
dict[p.name] = something

when you change p.name to 'Joe', do you expect the dictionary mapping to magically change to dict['Joe']?

Comment: Even if I replace the property `widget.last_line` by a function call like `widget.get_last_line()`, the compiler treats the entry as a constant value (evaluated at compile-time). The only way to avoid this seems to be a lambda construct as posted by Blckknght above

Comment: yes, that's correct, but the lambda construct didn't come to my mind at first :)